# Criação de um site e um back-end com frameworks PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, framework, silex

Estou criando um site com sistema de back-end.

Sempre fiz este processo utilizando apenas um framework como Laravel ou Codeigniter, mas conversando com algumas pessoas mais experientes neste assunto, recomendaram utilizar Codeigniter ou Laravel só para o back-end e usar o silex que é uma micro framework.

A recomendação surgiu pelo fato de o silex ser mais rápido que estes macro frameworks. Gostaria de saber se isso realmente procede, ou posso continuar utilizando como venho fazendo?

Comment: Nunca use o codeigniter. Se quer desempenho use o [phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/) é um framework feito como uma extensão, agora o quanto mais rápido ele é não sei dizer.

Comment: @rray concordo que `Codeigniter` é ruim, mas seu comentário demonstrou um grande teor de ódio pelo framework :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters com motivo né ;)

Comment: Recomendar usar Codeigniter atualmente é como pedir para usarem clipper numa aplicação desktop :)

Comment: Cara tomei -1 minha questão está para ser excluída, sendo que a minha pergunta é baseada na velocidade das frameworks...nossa cara!!! O que está acontecendo com o stack br??? A melhor resposta que tive foi a primeira que votei pq mostra gráficos....que absurdo isso!

Answer (score 1):

De forma resumida, a afirmação de seus amigos procede. Grandes frameworks como Laravel ajudam o desenvolvedor a simplificar inúmeras tarefas tediosas do dia a dia, porém isso tem um custo. Eles carregam diversos pacotes que muita das vezes não são utilizados por sua aplicação,o que acaba gerando um overhead.

Já um microframework é mais rápido devido a quantidade pequena de pacotes que carrega intrinsecamente consigo, você terá que instalar manualmente algum pacote que não venha por padrão, o que gera um trabalho extra porém melhora na performasse.

Se você quer mesmo é velocidade, recomendo utilizar o [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/pt/) ele é um full-stack framework, porém como é escrito em C, sua velocidade e monstruosa. Abaixo segue um benchmark para você ter uma ideia do quão rápido ele é.

[image: Comaração entre frameworks]

Answer (score 0):

O que é mais importante para você? Execução da aplicação ou a velocidade de desenvolvimento?

Embora o micro framework seja naturalmente mais leve, ele não terá todos os recursos de um framework full stack, que já incluem tudo isso de forma bem integrada.

Você pode criar todas essas integrações em um micro framework, mas você quer ter que manter esse tipo de código na sua aplicação? As bibliotecas que sua aplicação utiliza podem sofrer atualizações e você vai precisar alterar esse código.

Tudo depende do objetivo do seu projeto. Muita gente recomenda os micro frameworks por estar em evidencia. E realmente faz sentido usar o micro framework se temos uma arquitetura em micro services, onde todos os recursos de um full stack se tornam dispensáveis.

Entretanto, qual a vantagem de **começar** com um micro framework e implementar **90%** de um framework full stack **e** ter que manter **toda** essa integração?

Concluindo, os micro frameworks tem uma performance melhor, pois tem menos recursos. Porém a cada recurso ou integração que você precisar, mais overload será adicionado, chegando até a passar um full stack se não fizermos da melhor forma. Já com um full stack, você vai carregar coisas que não precisa, porém tudo que você precisa utilizar já está integrado e basta usar.